# Need to add validation on custom heap box

Tags: magento-1.9

```
<div class="heap" style="display: none;">
    <ul class="heapOptions">
        <li class="heapOption">
            <a href="" rel="" title="-- Please Select --" class="">-- Please Select --</a>
        </li>
        <li class="heapOption">
            <a href="" rel="11" title="Signature " class="">Signature </a>
        </li>
        <li class="heapOption">
            <a href="" rel="10" title="Southern Comfort " class="selected">Southern Comfort </a>
        </li>
        <li class="heapOption">
            <a href="" rel="49" title="Signature-Southern Blend " class="">Signature-Southern Blend </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Js Code:

```
if(!$("#checkoutSteps").length){
    if($("select").length){
            $("select").heapbox({
                    'onChange':function(value, elem){       
                    if(elem[0].name == 'blgcategory'){
                    if (value != '') {                  
                    window.location.href = value;
                    }
                    }
                }
            });         
        }
    }
```

Above Html not have validation when we click on Add to cart.
can you please let me know how we can put validation on customized heapOptions.
https://www.cacaoandcardamom.com/the-perfect-selection

Comment: Is that custom options or some customization you have done?

Comment: It's custom option.
I just change design using this code.
if(!$("#checkoutSteps").length){
 if($("select").length){
   $("select").heapbox({
     'onChange':function(value, elem){  
     if(elem[0].name == 'blgcategory'){
     if (value != '') {     
     window.location.href = value;
     }
     }
    }
   });   
  }
 }

Comment: Are your field set is required to yes?

Comment: Yes, Because I need to select anyone from the list.
I know this is due to is select "Yes". But I need to validate when someone clicks on Add to cart.
Did you check added a link or not?

Comment: edit it in your question its not readable in comment

Comment: @Priyank I edited.